# Spring/Jaxb2Marshaller/MOXy not loading package-info.java namespace mappings

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, moxy

## Problem

I'm getting some strange behavior where the Spring `Jaxb2Marshaller` doesn't scan my `package-info.java`.  Could anyone take a look?

I have a Spring MVC/Camel application that accepts multiple objects that are wrapped with a generic wrapper, where the XML MUST look like:

```
<mlf:message id="22" product="great.event" xmlns:mlf="special mlf URI">
    <mlf:header>
        <mlf:action value="notify-published"/>
    </mlf:header>
    <mlf:payload status="partial">
        <can be any element at all>
    </mlf:payload>
</mlf:message>
```

My setup follows the Error.

## Error

-00:00 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR                                               o.s.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jaxb2Marshaller' defined in class path resource [com/company/CamelConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is

...

Exception [EclipseLink-25016] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A namespace for the prefix mlf:header was not found in the namespace resolver.

- with linked exception:
  [Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]

## Setup

My package-info.java and Wrapper classes look like this:

package-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(
    xmlns={
        @XmlNs(prefix="mlf", namespaceURI="special mlf URI")
    },
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)

package com.company.camel;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Message.java

```
package com.company.camel;
@XmlRootElement(name = "message", namespace = "special mlf URI")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message {

    @XmlAttribute(required = false)
    private int id;

    @XmlAttribute(namespace = "")
    private String product;

    @XmlAttribute(namespace = "", required = false)
    private String type;

    @XmlPath("flm:header/flm:action/@value")
    private String action;

    @XmlPath("flm:header/flm:notify-failure/@type")
    private String notifyFailureType;

    @XmlPath("flm:header/flm:notify-failure/@value")
    private String notifyFailureValue;

    @XmlPath("flm:payload")
    private Payload payload;

    //SNIP
}
```

Payload.java

```
package com.company.camel;
@XmlRootElement(name="payload", namespace="special mlf URI")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Payload {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String status;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    Object body;

    //Getters&setters snipped
}
```

Because I need to unmarshal this class from Spring MVC REST and Camel (no I cannot use Camel for REST), I set up JAXB in Spring like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.company.camel")
public class CamelConfig extends CamelConfiguration
{

    //SNIP

// The JAXBDataFormat is used inside Camel routes 
@Bean
public JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat() {
    return new JaxbDataFormat(jaxb2Marshaller().getJaxbContext());
}

//used directly by Spring MVC
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.company"});
    return marshaller;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noticed that you had another unanswered question... my condolences, JAXB can be a pain to troubleshoot.  Could you perhaps post the entire project?

We had a large Spring project where Spring loaded JAXB-annotated classes, complete with package-info.java files, from an imported JAR.

Then another developer added code to manually call JAXBContext.newInstance on a class ***in the same package*** as a class in the imported JAR.  This new class was not in the imported JAR, the new class was in the main project.  ***Additionally, there was no package-info in the main project for that package.***

Pretty sure the original JAXB package mapping from the imported JAR was being blown away and replaced.

Look for any additional calls to JAXB that shouldn't be there.

Comment: So... was that the problem?